# R incongruity when copying a column in R with ifelse

Tags: r, string, dataframe, if-statement, seq

After loading lots of xlsx sheets of multiple workbooks, I want to create a double check of the tidiness and cleanliness of the data source. I created a data frame reading the worksheets as.numeric (with the risk of NAs introduced by coercion)  and an other data frame reading the data *as it is* (with the risk of not having number value) . This is to confront them and to find if there could be some import problems and where the correction to do in the xlsx source workbooks.

When asking the sum, in the "non numerical" data frame I want to turn around the error (if the data are dirty..(not numerical))

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(c(1:10),c(1,2,"a","b",5,6,7,8,9,10)))
colnames(df) <- c("ColA","ColB")
df <- df[order(df$ColB),]

# if the values are not numerical,  
# I want to create a column with the formula to use in excel 
# to do the sum in xlsx (it should start with row+1 
# as there are the headers in xlsx). So I want just to put a string.

# Doing the below I always have the same unique string 
# for column NonNumeric1  "=SUM(A2:B2)", it is not what I want.

df$Total.NonNumeric1 <-   ifelse(sum(as.numeric(lapply(select(df, ColA:ColB),is.character)))>0, 
                                 paste("=SUM(A",1 + seq.int(nrow(df)),":B",1 + seq.int(nrow(df)),")",sep = ""), 
                                 select(df, ColA:ColB) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))

df
   ColA ColB Total.NonNumeric1
1     1    1       =SUM(A2:B2)
10   10   10       =SUM(A2:B2)
5     5    2       =SUM(A2:B2)
2     2    5       =SUM(A2:B2)
9     9    6       =SUM(A2:B2)
7     7    7       =SUM(A2:B2)
8     8    8       =SUM(A2:B2)
6     6    9       =SUM(A2:B2)
3     3    a       =SUM(A2:B2)
4     4    b       =SUM(A2:B2)


# I tried to turn around and create the column with the string 
# for each row, this worked without the ifelse.

df<- within(df,row_num <- paste("=SUM(A",1 + seq.int(nrow(df)),":B",1 + seq.int(nrow(df)),")",sep = ""))

# as you can see row_num is sequential
df
   ColA ColB Total.NonNumeric1       row_num
1     1    1       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A2:B2)
10   10   10       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A3:B3)
5     5    2       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A4:B4)
2     2    5       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A5:B5)
9     9    6       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A6:B6)
7     7    7       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A7:B7)
8     8    8       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A8:B8)
6     6    9       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A9:B9)
3     3    a       =SUM(A2:B2) =SUM(A10:B10)
4     4    b       =SUM(A2:B2) =SUM(A11:B11)

# but if I try to put it to replace the column Total.NonNumeric2 
#(that needs to be replace 
# with the string only if the data are not numerical, 
# it goes back to the same "=SUM(A2:B2)" 
# and does not keep the sequence or the original string. 

df$Total.NonNumeric2 <-   ifelse(sum(as.numeric(lapply(select(df, ColA:ColB),is.character)))>0,
                          df$row_num, 
                          select(df, ColA:ColB) %>% rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))

df
   ColA ColB Total.NonNumeric1       row_num Total.NonNumeric2
1     1    1       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A2:B2)       =SUM(A2:B2)
10   10   10       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A3:B3)       =SUM(A2:B2)
5     5    2       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A4:B4)       =SUM(A2:B2)
2     2    5       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A5:B5)       =SUM(A2:B2)
9     9    6       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A6:B6)       =SUM(A2:B2)
7     7    7       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A7:B7)       =SUM(A2:B2)
8     8    8       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A8:B8)       =SUM(A2:B2)
6     6    9       =SUM(A2:B2)   =SUM(A9:B9)       =SUM(A2:B2)
3     3    a       =SUM(A2:B2) =SUM(A10:B10)       =SUM(A2:B2)
4     4    b       =SUM(A2:B2) =SUM(A11:B11)       =SUM(A2:B2)
```

I would need that a column with the formula string is inserted only if the sum is not possible because characters, otherwise it should be the sum of the defined columns. But especially I would like to understand where is my error.
Thank you very much

Comment: I haven't run your code, but `lapply` returns a `list`, so `as.numeric(lapply` looks suspicious. Maybe try `sapply` instead?

Comment: But also, you're testing whether the columns are `character` class, but the way you create the sample data using `cbind()` if any columns are character class, they all will be. Maybe try `data.frame(c(1:10),c(1,2,"a","b",5,6,7,8,9,10))` for the sample data so `cbind` doesn't coerce everything to a matrix first.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments say, you are starting out with all `character` columns, but even if not, any column with mixed numbers and strings would be `character` anyway.  In that case, it might be better to do the `ifelse` element-wise instead of on the columns as a whole:

```r
# temp var y to avoid adding twice
df$Total.NonNumeric2 <- with(df, {
  y <- as.numeric(ColA) + as.numeric(ColB)
  # y <- as.character(y)

  ifelse(is.na(y), row_num, y)
})
df["Total.NonNumeric2"]
   Total.NonNumeric2
1                  2
10                20
2                  4
5                 10
6                 12
7                 14
8                 16
9                 18
3      =SUM(A10:B10)
4      =SUM(A11:B11)
```

I don't know how fragile this will be with the data in your spreadsheet, but should be ok with just numbers and letters.  Also, if all your values are numbers, then the result will be a numerical column.  Not sure what the rest of your code will do, but for robustness, you can coerce `y` to character.

Comment: thank you very much. the ifelse element-wise instead of on the columns as a whole helps a lot. I had to do some modification for the full dataset as I had not 2 columns but 250 to select out of 260.  I have not been able to do all the process inside the full dataset. So I  separated the 250 col as dataframe;  sapply them as numeric ; To avoid to have 0 as totals when na, I create a col total.NonNumeric2 with x$Total.NonNumeric2 <- ifelse(apply(is.na(x),1,all),NA,rowSums(x,na.rm=TRUE)) ;  Then retrieve this x$Total.NonNumeric2 as y and used your formula  ifelse(is.na(y), row_num, y).